# jsp-3 items in one row from database

Tags: jsp

i am trying to display items from database but i manage to fetch single item in a single from database but what i wanna do is to display atleast 3-4 items in one row and next 3-4 items in next row.
i am using this code right now

```
do
{           
  out.println("<tr><td><td><a href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'><img src='pimages/" + myresult.getString("image") + "' style='width:200px'></a></</td>"

              + "<td><h3><a href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'>" + myresult.getString("name") + "</a></h3><br>"
              + "<h5>" + myresult.getString("price")+ "</h5><br>"
              + "<b>Star Rating :" + myresult.getString("uid") + "</b></td>"
              + "<td><h3>Price</h3><h4><br>Rs." + myresult.getInt("price") + "/-Rs</h4><br>"
              + "<button name='details' class='btn btn-md btn-danger'><a style='color:white' href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'>Book Now</a></button></td>"
              + "</tr>");
}
```

Comment: add more code, this explains nothing. What does the code for the database logic look like? What about the code where you view this ? etc... What even is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First Create a blank String variable in jsp

```
String DisplayedData="";
```

Next is to loop through all records and append your html into that String variable so that you get all records:

```
do
{           
 DisplayedData=(new StringBuilder()).append("<tr><td><td><a href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'><img src='pimages/" + myresult.getString("image") + "' style='width:200px'></a></</td>"

          + "<td><h3><a href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'>" + myresult.getString("name") + "</a></h3><br>"
          + "<h5>" + myresult.getString("price")+ "</h5><br>"
          + "<b>Star Rating :" + myresult.getString("uid") + "</b></td>"
          + "<td><h3>Price</h3><h4><br>Rs." + myresult.getInt("price") + "/-Rs</h4><br>"
          + "<button name='details' class='btn btn-md btn-danger'><a style='color:white' href='hoteldetails.jsp?id=" + myresult.getString("uid") + "'>Book Now</a></button></td>"
          + "</tr>").append(DisplayedData);
}
```

At the end display this variable will show all your records :

```
out.println(DisplayedData);
```

Comment: I am already getting all the records by the previous code......but they are displayed as single record in single row ....all i wanna do is to show 3-4 items in a single row like other e-commerce websites.